# RedisInsight: Configuring graph visual display/results?

Tags: redisgraph, redisinsights

Is there a way to configure the display of RedisGraph results in RedisInsight.
May be an option to edit the CSS directly is good too.

The reasons :

- The color of the nodes is awful
- The font-size is too small
- nice to be able to change color of nodes with property value X
- it will be good to be able to specify the default-property that will be displayed instead of node ID. Also on mouse-over too. (i know i can changed but it becomes tedious to do it for every result).
- same for relationships
- ERR: If some of the nodes in the result does not have the property you  want to switch to (for display), then the 'switch' does not work i.e. all nodes still display IDs
- for my screen it just  happen that the +/- zoom is hidden i.e. I have to scroll back and forth. It will be good if we can use the keyboard to zoomin/zoomout
- once you select something you have to click outside of the graph area to be able to scroll, supper annoying
- command history on the query editor would be nice
- ability to pin the result-area so that the new result does not spawn yet another area .. it is nice to have the option for multiple result-areas, but the normal interaction is refining queries rather than writing  new query every time. (tabs would have been better)
- if possible select-area to zoom will be nice. (by holding mouse down and selecting area )
- !! double-click outside a node, may Zoom, instead of doing nothing
- !! local zoom/search : typing in search-bar (there is space for it after +/-) to zoomin on the node with that have property and/or value f.e.  val:3 , word:test , ...

Posting this here because couldn't find a place to give feedback on RedisInsight !